# Creating optimal shopping list based on given conditions

Tags: java, optimization, combinatorics

I am trying to create shopping lists from a collection of products, where the returned shopping list should be optimized for cost as well as to meet another condition.

For example, let's say that I want to create shopping lists based on the energy content of the products. When the user enters a total sum, the returned shopping list should try to max out the kcal content while keeping the total sum at or around the sum specified by the user.

I've gotten so far as to create the collection of products, and all products are stored as objects with fields holding nutritional values and price etc. The kcal-value is also stored as a member variable in each product's object.

At first I considered looping through all combinations of products, sort out those that are way out of the price interval, and then return the one with the highest kcal content. But as the numbers of products available increases this soon becomes a non-viable option I think.

I now wonder if there is any algorithm to solve this problem, if not, is there any way to easily implement this?

Comment: It's more of a math problem than an algorithmic one. It looks like a linear problem, which is a class of problems for which a lot of techniques are known. In your particular case the solutions are vectors of integers so that may be a bit more difficult, but I've lost too much of my math skills to tell you

Comment: Yeah, something that popped up in my mind was diophantine equation-solving, as integer solutions are the only viable solutions. But apart from that, I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similiar with Dynamic Programming [Wikipedia article on Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

In the following costs and values should be arrays of the same length. The length of the possible items to choose from. The capacity is the maximum sum of all the costs of items you choose. It returns an array of booleans of the same length determining whether to take the item or not.

The idea is to create a table with the solutions to sub-problems that can then be used to solve a bigger problem.  The sub-problems just solve the same problem but with a smaller list, initially with only one item. The table contains the best value you can get with the first i items for each weight up to the maximum.  As you add one potential item to the list you add its value to the previous solution for that allowed weight minus the weight your adding and check if that is better than the previous solution without the last item. Once the last row is created you can tell which items to take by checking for where there are differences in the values in that last row.

```
public boolean[] solve(int[] values, int[] costs, int capacity) {
    boolean take[] = new boolean[values.length];
    int min_cost = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (costs[i] < min_cost) {
            min_cost = costs[i];
        }
    }
    int table[][] = new int[values.length][capacity + 1 - min_cost];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        int v = values[i];
        int w = costs[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < capacity - min_cost + 1; j++) {
            int prev_value = 0;
            int new_value = 0;
            if (i > 0) {
                prev_value = table[i - 1][j];
                if (w <= j + min_cost) {
                    if (w <= j) {
                        new_value = table[i - 1][j - w] + v;
                    } else {
                        new_value = v;
                    }
                }
            } else if (w <= j + min_cost) {
                new_value = v;
            }
            table[i][j] = Math.max(prev_value, new_value);
        }
    }
    int index = capacity - min_cost;
    for (int i = values.length - 1; i > 0 && index >= 0; i--) {
        if (table[i][index] != table[i - 1][index]) {
            take[i] = true;
            index -= costs[i];
            if (index < 0) {
                System.err.println("index = " + index);
            }
        } else {
            take[i] = false;
        }
    }
    take[0] = index >= 0 && table[0][index] != 0;
    return take;
}
```